# Selectable text with ExpertPdf HtmlToPdf Converter

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I'm using this code (ExpertPDF API) to create a pdf from a HTML page :

```
PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = true;            
pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "my pdf converti";
byte[] downloadBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfFromUrlBytes("https://community.nitrous.io/docs/preview-a-static-html-page");

if (System.IO.File.Exists("test2.pdf"))
{
   System.IO.File.Delete("test2.pdf");
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("test2.pdf", downloadBytes);
```

When I run the application on my computer, the pdf containts a non selectable text but when I run it on another computer (with almoust same configuration), the pdf containts a selectable text.

I need it to be selectable all the time.

Configuration : Windows 7, .NET Version : 4.6, ephtmltopdf.dll: 6.2